# First node in \pnodes starting at non-zero index

Tags: pst-node

I'm using the [`pst-node`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) package. Is it possible to let the first node name from `\pnodes`[*] start at, say, `P8` instead of `P0`? (In general, something other than `P0`.)

[*] See page 39 of the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-node/pst-node-doc.pdf).

**Update**

Here is the code that I produced quite a long time ago. I think it can be made somewhat simpler without changing much if I can use `\pnodes` with the first node name starting a `$P_i$ for $i \neq 0$`.

```
% pdflatex -shell-escape test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,0)(11.4,15.8)
 \pnode(0,0){P1}
 \pnode(0,9.5){P2}
 \pnode(1.05,9.5){P3}
 \pnode(1.05,11.6){P4}
 \pnode(0,11.6){P5}
 \pnode(0,15){P6}
 \pnode(10.5,15){P7}
 \pnode(10.5,5.7){P8}
 \pnode(11.4,4.8){P9}
 \pnode(10.5,4.8){P10}
 \pnode(10.5,1.2){P11}
 \pnode(11.4,0.3){P12}
 \pnode(10.5,0.3){P13}
 \pnode(10.5,0){P14}
 \pnode(9.6,0){P15}
 \pnode(9.6,0.9){P16}
 \pnode(8.7,0){P17}
 \psline(P17)(P1)(P2)(P3)
 \psline(P4)(P5)(P6)(P7)(P8)
 \psline(P9)(P10)(P11)
 \psline(P12)(P13)(P14)(P15)(P16)
 \psIntersectionPoint(P1)(P7)(P6)(P14){P18}
 \rput(P18){\textbf{Studie}}
 \pnode(4.5,9){P21}
 \pnode(4.5,14){P22}
 \pnode(9.5,14){P23}
 \pnode(9.5,9){P24}
 \pspolygon(P21)(P22)(P23)(P24)
 \psIntersectionPoint(P21)(P23)(P22)(P24){P25}
 \rput(P25){\text{Sofagruppe}}
 \pnode(7,2.5){P31}
 \pnode(7,7.5){P32}
 \pnode(8.5,7.5){P33}
 \pnode(8.5,2.5){P34}
 \pspolygon(P31)(P32)(P33)(P34)
 \psIntersectionPoint(P31)(P33)(P32)(P34){P35}
 \rput{90}(P35){\text{Diskussionspanel}}
 \pnode(2,2){P41}
 \pnode(2,3.2){P42}
 \pnode(3.6,3.2){P43}
 \pnode(3.6,2){P44}
 \pspolygon(P41)(P42)(P43)(P44)
 \psIntersectionPoint(P41)(P43)(P42)(P44){P45}
 \rput(P45){\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{\centering\small Nyheds-\\ pult}}
 \pnode(!14 5 div 4 5 div 6 3 sqrt add mul){P46}
 \psdot(P46)
 \uput[90](P46){\text{Kamera}}
 \pnode(2.8,3.2){P47}
 \pcline[linestyle=dashed](P46)(P47)
 \ncput*{$d$}
\psset{
  linestyle=dotted
}
 \psline(P46)(P42)
% dist(P46,P42) = dist(P46,P43) = 8/5*sqrt(2+sqrt(3)) = 3,09
 \psline(P46)(P43)
 \psarc(P2){1.05}{0}{90}
 \psarc(P5){1.05}{270}{360}
 \psarc(P10){0.9}{0}{90}
 \psarc(P13){0.9}{0}{90}
 \psarc(P15){0.9}{90}{180}
\psset{
  arrows=|-|,
  linestyle=dashed,
  offset=12pt,
  nrot=:U
}
 \pcline(P1)(P6)
 \ncput*{15{,}0}
 \pcline(P6)(P7)
 \ncput*{10{,}5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If someone (Herbert?...) can make the drawing with some much simpler code, I will gladly see it.

**Update 2**

Here is what I have now, adapting Herbert's idea.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}

\def\door(#1,#2)#3{%
  \psline[
    linecolor=white,
    linewidth=5\pslinewidth,
    dimen=middle
  ](#1,#2)(!#1 #2 #3 add)
  \psline(#1,#2)(!#1 #3 add #2)
  \psarc[
    linestyle=dotted
  ](#1,#2){#3}{0}{90}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,0)(11.4,15.8)
 \psframe(0,0)(10.5,15)
 \rput[lb]{90}(9.6,0){\door(0,0){0.9}}
 \door(10.5,0.3){0.95}
 \door(10.5,4.8){0.95}
 \door(0,9.5){1.05}
 \rput(5.25,7.5){\textbf{Studie}}
 \rput(0,11.6){\psscalebox{1 -1}{\door(0,0){1.05}}}
 \psTextFrame(4.5,9)(9.5,14){Sofagruppe}
  \psTextFrame(7,2.5)(8.5,7.5){\rotatebox{90}{Diskussionspanel}}
 \psTextFrame(2,2)(3.6,3.2){\parbox{0.1\textwidth}{\centering\small{Nyheds-\\ pult}}}
 \pnode(!2.8 0.8 6 3 sqrt add mul){P}
 \psdot(P)
 \uput[90](P){Kamera}
\psset{linestyle=dotted}
 \psline(P)(2,3.2)
 \psline(P)(3.6,3.2)
 \pcline[
   linestyle=dashed
 ](P)(2.8,3.2)
 \ncput*{$d$}
\psset{
  arrows=|-|,
  linestyle=dashed,
  offset=12pt,
  nrot=:U
}
 \pcline(0,0)(0,15)     \ncput*{15{,}0}
 \pcline(0,15)(10.5,15) \ncput*{10{,}5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Can the non-Herbert part be drawn even simpler?

Comment: The feature you requested is too localized. :-) Zero-based index should be enough for most cases.

Comment: @Bugbusters That was a shame. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Herbert I have a drawing, made a long time ago when I started learning PSTricks, and the code and be made somewhat simpler without changing anything (almost). (I'll update my question with a MWE in a few minutes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 \pnodes{P}(0,0)(0,0)(0,9.5)(1.05,9.5)(1.05,11.6)(0,11.6)(0,15)(10.5,15)(10.5,5.7)%
    (11.4,4.8)(10.5,4.8)(10.5,1.2)(11.4,0.3)(10.5,0.3)(10.5,0)(9.6,0)(9.6,0.9)(8.7,0)
```

saves a lot of keystrokes. Double `(0,0)` to get the old counting.
Defining a macro `\door` makes also life easier. `psTextFrame` can be used for text in a frame. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pstricks-add}

\def\door(#1,#2)#3{%
  \psline[
    linecolor=white,
    linewidth=5\pslinewidth](#1,#2)(!#1 #2 #3 add)
  \psline(#1,#2)(!#1 #3 add #2)
  \psarc[
    linestyle=dotted
  ](#1,#2){#3}{0}{90}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,0)(11.4,15.8)
 \psTextFrame(0,0)(10.5,15){\textbf{Studie}}
 \rput[lb]{90}(9.6,0){\door(0,0){0.9}}
 \door(10.5,0.3){0.95}
 \door(10.5,4.8){0.95}
 \door(0,9.5){1.05}
 \rput(0,11.6){\psscalebox{1 -1}{\door(0,0){1.05}}}
 \psTextFrame(4.5,9)(9.5,14){Sofagruppe}
 \psTextFrame(7,2.5)(8.5,7.5){\rotatebox{90}{Diskussionspanel}}
 \psTextFrame(2,2)(3.6,3.2){\parbox{0.1\textwidth}{\small Nyheds-\\ pult}}
 \pnode(!2.8 0.8 6 3 sqrt add mul){P}
 \psdot(P) \uput[90](P){Kamera}
 \psline[linestyle=dotted](3.6,3.2)(P)(2,3.2)
 \pcline[linestyle=dashed](P)(2.8,3.2)\ncput*{$d$}
\psset{
  arrows=|-|,
  linestyle=dashed,
  offset=12pt,
  nrot=:U}
 \pcline(0,0)(0,15)     \ncput*{15{,}0}
 \pcline(0,15)(10.5,15) \ncput*{10{,}5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\psTextFrame(0,0)(10.5,15){\textbf{Studie}}` for the first frame and only one psline for the dotted one. See edit

Comment: All open curves except for `\psellipticarc` have `dimen=middle` by default so `dimen=middle` in the `door`  wastes keystrokes. :-)